# Copy Text with Syntax Highlighting option not available in Notepad++ plugin commands

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting, copy, paste

I'm trying to copy code from Notepad++ and copy the formatting to MSWord.  I have this on one PC and it works fine, but it is downloaded to another and the option to Copy Text with Syntax Highlighting isn't in the plugin command options.

Answer (score 0):

On a second PC, there will probably be a Notepad++ version with a different installation of the plugins. Not all plugins are available for 32bit or 64bit either. But that is not a problem here.

From the main menu, please go to Plugins > Plugins Admin and check whether NppExport is available on the **Installed** tab (as shown in the screenshot).

I assume you still have to install the Plugin NppExport.

[image]

Comment: Yes. That resolved the issue. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: @Christy - you're welcome. If an answer has helped you solve your problem feel free to upvote and mark the answer as accepted.